# In Rust program how to get an account's mint token balance (not SOL balance)

Tags: rust

Within my Rust program I would like to get the mint token balance of an account. I found the spl_token sdk but it only has functions to convert from a balance to a ui balance. I saw that an account has an amount field but this seems to be for the SOL amount or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Anchor`.

```
#[account(
mut,
associated_token::mint=mint,
associated_token::authority=user,
)]
pub user_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
```

```
user_token_account.amount
```

The `SOL` is accessed by `lamports()`.

You can use `reload` after the `CPI` to get the updated value.

https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/CPIs.html#reloading-an-account

Comment: Thank you for your response. So then it is the amount field. Unfortunately it appears that since calls to transfer do not complete immediately getting the balance immediately after the transfer does not work. Is there a way to wait some time within a Solana program or would this not be allowed since it can cause a delay or program completion.

Comment: Not sure, but if you know how much you're transferring and you get the transfer result. You can manage it yourself.

Comment: What you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to log token balances so that a backend system can later retrieve the pre transfer and post transfer balances (we would use the web3js connection.getTransaction function's logMessages field). I don't want to just log the transfer on execution because there's always a small chance a transfer could fail. That's why I need to log it upon commit.

Comment: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#ParsedTransactionMeta => preBalances/postBalances doesn't have what you need?. In general if a transfer failed you probably abort the transaction. So if you insist on relying on msg! , just print it after the transfer finished. Store value prior, store transfer value, print the diff/sum after.

Comment: The reason why getting the balance immediately after the transfer appears to not work is NOT because transfers are not completed immediately. As @OhadDahan already mentioned, you need to call the user_token_account.reload()?` function after a cpi call to fetch the updated state of the token account. Otherwise there won't be a change to `user_token_account.balance` and it would wrongly seem like the transfer wasn't completed.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using pure Solana Rust and not Anchor, this is how to do it, assuming `Token-2022` program:

```
use spl_token_2022::{
    state::Account,
    extension::StateWithExtensions,
};

// ATA => Associated Token Account
// ata_info => &AccountInfo
// mint_info => &AccountInfo
let ata_data = ata_info.data.borrow();
let ata_state = StateWithExtensions::<Account>::unpack(&ata_data)?;

// Always check if you got the correct ATA for the mint
if &ata_state.base.mint != &mint_info.key {
    msg!("Token account doesn't match the expected mint");
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
}

msg!("balance={}", ata_state.base.amount);
```

For reference, the deserialized struct from the associated token account looks like this:

```
StateWithExtensions {
  base: Account {
    mint: 5zpRyR6d3cd3kBvkcjvqsLqQqPzoCbuyLtBTaE6mSvH3,
    owner: 7Lf9P1Ez7KuevTi2fgB8E4XRAMEWg74d7W2nbteT5oHW,
    amount: 1,
    delegate: None,
    state: Frozen,
    is_native: None,
    delegated_amount: 0,
    close_authority: None
  },
  tlv_data: [7, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

In case you are still using the old `Token` program:

```
use spl_token::state::Account;

// ATA => Associated Token Account
// ata_info => &AccountInfo
// mint_info => &AccountInfo
let ata_data = ata_info.data.borrow();
let ata_state = Account::unpack(&ata_data)?;

// Always check if you got the correct ATA for the mint
if &ata_state.mint != &mint_info.key {
    msg!("Token account doesn't match the expected mint");
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
}

msg!("balance={}", ata_state.amount);
```

The struct stored in `ata_state` has the following shape:

```
pub struct Account {
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub delegate: COption<Pubkey>,
    pub state: AccountState,
    pub is_native: COption<u64>,
    pub delegated_amount: u64,
    pub close_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
}
```